# What does ulConfig |= ulMode; mean?

Tags: c, microcontroller

I am not really sure what does `ulConfig |= ulMode;` mean? If

```
void gpio_setup_mode(unsigned long ulGpioNum, unsigned long ulMode, unsigned long ulInvert)
{
  unsigned long ulConfig = ulInvert;
  ulConfig |= ulMode;
  s_ptGPIO->auiCFG[ulGpioNum] = ulConfig;
}
```

and

```
 gpio_setup_mode(GPIO8,  GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT,     GPIO_NOINVERT);
```

where GPIO8,  GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT,     GPIO_NOINVERT

```
#define GPIO8                         8    
#define GPIO_NOINVERT         0x00000000 
#define GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT     0x00000011
```

Comment: there are several lines of code regarding a gpio setup sequence.  You did not ask any question about those lines.  However, what they do is: GPIO port 8 bits 0 and 1 are set as outputs and the outputs are not inverted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ulConfig |= ulMode;
```

is equivalent to

```
ulConfig = ulConfig | ulMode;
```

The `|`-operator performs a binary "or" operation between the two operants.

From the C11-Standard (Draft):

> **6.5.12 Bitwise inclusive OR operator**
>
> [...]
>
> **Contrains**
>
> 2 Each of the operands shall have integer type.
>
> **Semantics**
>
> [...]
>
> 4 The result of the | operator is the bitwise inclusive OR of the operands (that is, each bit in
>   the result is set if and only if at least one of the corresponding bits in the converted
>   operands is set).

Comment: `ulConfig` is a local, temporary variable to store the result of `ulInvert | ulMode;`.Instead of the 1st two lines one also could have written: `unsigned long ulConfig =  ulInvert | ulMode;` Sometime there are more than one way to implement a certain logic. @user3826752

Comment: Hi. Can you explain please what does                                                #define GPIO_CFG_MODE_IN_READ (0x0 << 3)
#define GPIO_CFG_IOCFG_IN (0x0 << 0)  mean? This i dont understand (0x0 << 0) and (0x0 << 3). @ alk

Comment: @user3826752: This not related to this question at all. So it ought to become a new question.

Comment: Sad( I can ask a new question only through 4 days. @alk